# Iterate data from Express to EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, ejs

I'm really confuse for this:

```
<script>
    const i = 0
    const data = "<%= dataMedico[0].user %>" // Fine
    const data2 = `<%= dataMedico[${i}].user %>` // Error
</script>
```

It supose that the second one uses the constant "**i**" to return me the value "**user**", but it only returnes me this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{' in myRoot\views\index.ejs while compiling ejs

I need to iterate the **dataMedico** to comparate the users with the data of a form like this:

```
function verificator() {
        for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            const userMedicos = `<% dataMedico[${i}].usuario %>`
            const passwordMedicos = `<% dataMedico[${i}].contrasenia %>`

            const text = document.getElementById("user").value
            const pass1 = document.getElementById("password").value

            if (text === userMedicos && pass1 === passwordMedicos) {
                button.href = "principal"
            } else {
                alert("ERROR.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Do you recomend me another way to make it more easy?

Comment: The Javascript template string is evaluated when your Javascript is parsed by the browser, NOT when the page is rendered by EJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Javascript template string is evaluated when your Javascript is parsed by the browser, NOT when the page is rendered by EJS.  If the end goal here is to make your `verificator()` function work in the Javascript in your web page, then you will need to render the entire `dataMedico` data into a variable in the page's Javascript using EJS.

Then, your page's Javascript can reference that data like it would any Javascript variable's data.

So, here's how you embed the `dataMedico` data into your page as a Javascript variable.

```
<script>
    const dataMedico = <%- JSON.stringify(dataMedico) %>;
</script>
```

You can then use that in your `verificator()` function like this:

```
<script>

function verificator() {
        for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            const userMedicos = dataMedico[i].usuario;
            const passwordMedicos = dataMedico[i].contrasenia;

            const text = document.getElementById("user").value
            const pass1 = document.getElementById("password").value

            if (text === userMedicos && pass1 === passwordMedicos) {
                button.href = "principal"
            } else {
                alert("ERROR.");
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Please note that the `verificator()` function appears to be incomplete.  You're running a loop 10 times, but your `else` will `alert()` possibly as many as 10 times.  I presume you do not really want that.